# Can't determine reference in a posted example

Tags: vuetify.js, vuelidate

I'm trying to use the Vuetify Form with validation and have tried to use the example at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms (Example: #vuelidate) as a starting point.

In the script, the example references a '$v' which I presume is a validation object of some sort.  I have completely failed at trying to deduce where it is coming from.

I have attempted a variety of imports ('vuelidate', 'vuelidate/lib/validators') and been down a number of chains using npm to add to my component base, but with no luck.

Can someone enlighten me on where $v is coming from and if I need to do more than exploit the imports shown in the script.

Thanks for your help,
  --Don

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a reference (https://monterail.github.io/vuelidate/#sub-v-values) which seems to give me the info I was looking for.    Not sure it is the proper one, but it gives me a start at resolving my problems.
   -D